# How to use pthread_tryjoin_np() to know if a pthread was terminated via pthread_exit

Tags: c, pthreads

My current assignment tasked me with a producer/consumer problem with multiple threads. I currently have the producer-consumer problem implemented, however, there is also another part to the assignment where we have to simulate our threads crashing. Apparently this is done by calling `pthread_exit(NULL);`. I was given a hint to use `pthread_tryjoin_np()`, but I can't seem to get it to work.
My current implementation of the joining with `pthread_tryjoin_np()` is:

```
for(i = 0; i < numThread; i++) {
    if(pthread_tryjoin_np(th[i], NULL) != 0) {
        pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, &consumer, NULL);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I am using `pthread_tryjoin_np()` incorrectly, but a fix using `pthread_tryjoin_np()` or another solution would be great.

Comment: It seems the instructor does not understand the API they're trying to teach. Threads **cannot crash**. If a thread does something that generates an unhandled fatal signal, the **process** terminates. "Check if our thread crashed and restart it" makes no sense whatsoever as an operation. Your thread cannot exit without you choosing to make it exit.

Answer (score 2):

As I noted initially in a comment:

> It seems the instructor does not understand the API they're trying to teach. Threads **cannot crash**. If a thread does something that generates an unhandled fatal signal, the **process** terminates. "Check if our thread crashed and restart it" makes no sense whatsoever as an operation. Your thread cannot exit without you choosing to make it exit.

However if you want to do this anyway to make them happy, your problem is just that your condition is backwards; you have `!= 0` where `== 0` is what you mean. `pthread_tryjoin_np` succeeds (returns 0) if and only if the thread has exited.

Comment: The OP should also recognize that the `_np` in the function name is mnemonic for "nonportable".  This function is a GNU extension, which is fine if you only care about Glibc-based systems, but not so good if you are interested in broader applicability.

Comment: Well it does work better now, however, because of the non blocking aspect of pthread_tryjoin_np the loop will iterate completely before anything is produced. Essentially there is no chance for anything to even crash before the loop has been completed.

Comment: Well yes, you'd have to repeat it, preferably not spinning at 100% cpu load but instead waiting for the event of at least one thread having terminated. There's no way to do that with `pthread_tryjoin_np`; instead you'd do it by having the threads tell you, via a data protected by a mutex and signaled with a condition variable, that they've exited. All of this is highlighting that what yout instructor has in mind **makes no sense** and is based on fundamental misunderstanding of pthread API.